# How to estimate $dist (a,Tx)$ where $Tx$ is closed and bounded.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, supremum-and-infimum, hausdorff-distance

This is, actually, part of my research work. I'm finding it hard to understand how it came about since I have to explain it later.

Let $X=\mathbb{R}$ be with the usual metric and $K(X)$ be the family of nonempty compact subsets of $X.$ Define multivalued map, $ T:X\rightarrow K(X)$ by 
$$
 \begin{eqnarray}
 Tx=\begin{cases}
 \left[-4x,-\dfrac{7}{2}x \right],&x\in \left[0,\infty \right),\\
 \left[-\dfrac{7}{2}x ,-4x\right],&x\in \left(-\infty, 0\right].
 \end{cases}
 \end{eqnarray}
$$
Suppose $x,y\in \left(0,\infty \right)\cup \left(-\infty,0 \right),$ then
\begin{align}
H(Tx,Ty)&=\max\left\lbrace \sup\limits_{a\in Tx}dist(a,Ty),\sup\limits_{b\in Ty}dist(Tx,b) \right\rbrace \\&=\max\left\lbrace \sup\limits_{a\in Tx}\left( \inf\limits_{b\in Ty} d(a,b)\right) ,\sup\limits_{b\in Ty}\left( \inf\limits_{a\in Tx} d(a,b)\right)\right\rbrace\\&=\max\left\lbrace \sup\limits_{a\in Tx}\left( \inf\limits_{b\in Ty} |a-b|\right) ,\sup\limits_{b\in Ty}\left( \inf\limits_{a\in Tx} |a-b|\right)  \right\rbrace\\&=\max\left\lbrace \sup\limits_{a\in Tx} \left\lbrace |a+4y|\right\rbrace  ,\sup\limits_{b\in Ty}\left\lbrace  \left| -4x-b\right|  \right\rbrace  \right\rbrace\\&=\max\left\lbrace   4\left| x-y\right|,4\left| x-y\right| \right\rbrace  \\&=4\left| x-y\right|  
\end{align}

I think I got it all wrong when calculating 
$$\inf\limits_{b\in Ty} |a-b|,\inf\limits_{a\in Tx} |a-b|,$$
for fixed $a$ and $b$, respectively.

**Question:** Please, how do I get it? I mean $\inf\limits_{b\in Ty} |a-b|$ for a fixed $a$ in $Tx.$

Comment: I think that you have some mistake in the definition of $Tx$ because with that definition we have that $T1=[-2,-3.5]=\emptyset$

Comment: @Kanido mat: Thanks, let me edit. I was trying to avoid plagiarism.

Comment: @Kanido mat: Thanks, I've edited it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can assume without loss of generality that $0<y<x$. With this assumption we know that
$$-4x<-4y \ \ \mbox{ and } \ -\frac{7}{2}x <-\frac{7}{2}y.$$
Let $a \in Tx$ so that
$$-4x \leq a \leq -\frac{7}{2}x.$$
If $-\frac{7}{2}x \leq -4y$, then we have that the closest point from $Ty$ to $a$ is $-4y$ because in this case 
$$a \leq -4y \leq b$$
for all $b \in Ty$. Hence $d(a,Ty)=|a-(-4y)|=|a+4y|$ provided $-\frac{7}{2}x \leq -4y$.

On the other hand, if $-4y<-\frac{7}{2}x$, then we have that
$$-4x<-4y < -\frac{7}{2}x<-\frac{7}{2}y.$$
From this it follows that $d(a,Ty)=0$ if $-4y \leq a \leq -\frac{7}{2}x$ because in that case $a \in Ty$. If $-4x\leq a <-4y$ then $d(a,Ty)=|a-(-4y)|$.

Summing up, $d(a, Ty)=0$ if $a \in Tx \cap Ty$, and $d(a,Ty)=|a+4y|$ if $a \in Tx$ but $a \notin Ty$.